# How does one generate cryptographic signatures PKCS#7 in Java?

Tags: java, security, cryptography, keystore

I am trying to develop a module in Java (JDK 1.7), to apply a digital signature to digital documents with PKCS # 7 cryptographic envelopes.

I'm using the java class `KeyStore` (`java.security.KeyStore`), am in possession of a file `keystore.ks`, and I have the credentials (password).

The first thing I tried to print the certificates on the inside, with the following code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

      String keystoreFilename = PATH_TO_KEYSTORE;
      char[] password = KEYSTORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray();

      FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(keystoreFilename);

      KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSTORETYPE);


      Provider temp = keystore.getProvider();

      System.out.println(temp.getName());

      KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSTORETYPE);
      FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(PATH_TO_KEYSTORE);
      try {
           keystore.load(input, KEYSTORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
      } catch (IOException e) {
           System.out.println("ERROR:"+e.getMessage());
      } finally {
           if (input != null) {
                input.close();
           }
       }

      Certificate cert = keystore.getCertificate(KEY_ALIAS_IN_KEYSTORE);

      System.out.println(cert);
 }
```

This code returns the following:

```
error: "Invalid keystore format" (KEYSTORETYPE = "JKS")
```

When I try to carry the load of the certificates contained within it.

Could anyone tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your KEYSTORETYPE does not match the type used to create the file keystore.ks

There are a couple of different types available in the standard and additional ones from other providers.

The standard would be "jks", also very common is "pkcs12".